# How to find Xth palindrome?

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers, palindrome, time-limiting

**Dear Friends:**

- *As much as strings,* some numbers are also palindrome. For instance: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, ... , 101, 111, ... ,753537, ...  and so on.
- *Here is the thing,* We need to figure a way to find first 10.000 palindromic numbers in order to respond user's entry. Starts from 1 to 10000th palindromic number.  **For example if user enters 12 it means what is the 12th palindromic number between 1 and 10.000 ?**
- The input consists of a series of lines with each line containing one integer value i (1 <= i <= 10000). This integer value i indicates the index of the palindrome number that is to be written to the output, where index 1 stands for the first palindrome number (1), index 2 stands for the second palindrome number (2) and so on.

**EX:**

Input 1 --> Output should be: 1

Input 12 --> Output should be: 33

Input 24 --> Output should be: 151

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class xth_palindrome
    {
        // Some Code may be here

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter values as much as you want. To stop Enter \"0\" ");

            int Xth;

            do
            {
                Xth = read.nextInt();

                // Some coding here 

                System.out.println(Xth + " palindromic num is " + "????");

            } while(Xth != 0);
        }
    }
```

- By the way: **time limit is *1 second.*** *Considering these factors* What is the right Algorithm to solve this problem ? If you could help me and show the solution code wise in Java I would very appreciate it. Thanks for checking!

Comment: What do you mean you already know the first 10000 palindromic numbers? Would it not then be as simple as putting them into an array and checking `palindromeArray[Xth+1]`?

Comment: "Let's assume that we know the first 10,000..."  "databases are not allowed."  What do you mean by "database"?  How can your program "know" 10,000 facts if they're not in a database?  If your program has to compute the first 10,000 palindromic numbers then it doesn't _know_ them:  It knows how to _find_ them.

Comment: It is not evident what you need help with. Please post code of what you have already tried.

Comment: I think you could solve this by thinking about it this way: All 1-digit numbers are palindromes.  What 2-digit numbers are palindromes, how many are there, and if we were asked to find the Nth 2-digit palindrome, how would we do that?  Then do the same for 3-digit palindromes, 4-digit palindromes, and so on.  If you can compute how many of each there are, then you can say "if X is in 1-9 it must be one digit, if it's in 10 to (9+N) it must be 2 digits, if it's in 10+(10+N) to something, it must be 3 digits...

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the ambiguity. I meant we need to find a way.

Comment: I added some Sample Input and Output. You may also want to check.

Comment: An internet search engine reveals that this has been extensively studied and some results are [here](http://johanjeuring.blogspot.fi/2007/08/finding-palindromes.html).

Comment: FYI: I just noticed that the number 753537 that you posted in your question is not correct since it's not a palindrome (perhaps you meant 753357?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not "the very best way", but works fine.

And it does the job in less than 1 sec (depending of your hardware).

I've tested [here](http://goo.gl/OZ7Flh).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

            Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter values as much as you want (lower than 100000).\n To stop Enter \"0\" ");

            int Xth;

            do
            {
                Xth = read.nextInt();


                // Some coding here 
                if (Xth > 100000)
                {
                    System.out.println("Type a number lower than 100000");
                    continue;
                }
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000000; i++)
                {
                    if (!isPalindrome(i))
                        continue;

                    count++;
                    if (count == Xth)
                    {
                        System.out.println(Xth + "th palindromic number is " + i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (count != Xth)
                    System.out.println("I can't compute that!");


            } while(Xth != 0);
     }

     private static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     private static boolean isPalindrome(int i)
     {
        sb.setLength(0);
        sb.append(i);
        return  sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString());
     }
```

Comment: It is going to be a very late respond but first of all thank you very much for your answer it works perfect. Only one problem, in the worst-case scenario(When user enters ten thousand) it takes slightly more than 1 second to compute. If you have any other idea to improve this solution I would like to hear that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate through the palindromes quite quickly. Note that

1. If there is an odd palindrome ABCBA, the next larger palindrome will be ABDBA where D=C+1
2. If there is an even palindrome ABCCBA, the next larger palindrome will be ABDDBA where D=C+1

The reasoning is simple. Any other number will also increment a larger MSB and hence the next higher palindrome will have changes in the centre.

Now if C = 9, we will need to increment B and reset C to 0 making the cases become AE0EA and AE00EA where E=B+1. This method is easily extensible and you can iterate through palindromes. Since we need to find at most 10,000 of them, a second should be more than enough for an iterative approach.